# Windows 7 explorer - obtain bigger preview images in tile view

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, images, tiles

I have a folder called "Scan" where I put the scan files made by my copier:
they can be .pdf, b/w .tif, or color .jpg
I find useful to set the view for this folder as "tiles", so I get a small preview image, the name, type and size of the files.
What I want to do is to enlarge the preview image from the default 48 px to something like the double or even more. I have a big monitor with fair high dpi and would like bigger tiles.

Comment: Can't you just change the size of the icons?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `View` -> `Extra Large Icons`? This displays preview images larger than 200 * 200 on my machine.

[image]

The following images show the difference on my machine between `View` -> `Tiles` and `View` -> `Extra large icons`:

**View -> Tiles**

[image]

**View -> Extra large icons**

[image]

**"I would also like to see details like file name, type and size as in tiles"**

To see the image details (file name, type and size, etc) select an image. The details will then be dispayed in the status bar:

[image]

---

**Alternative Solution**

There is another possible solution documented at [Windows 7: Tile View Icon Size](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/276340-tile-view-icon-size.html)

This solution however involves a third party application and patching of `\ExplorerFrame.dll`.

**Warning**

I have not tried this solution and it involves changes to system files, so I would **not** recomend it. Try this at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks but I would also like to see details like file name, type and size as in tiles

Comment: I've converted your 'answer' to a comment. You may want to create a registered account and request a merger so you can take back ownership of this question